# Should I drop dbo from the database role db_owner?

Tags: sql-server, security, azure-sql-database, vulnerability-assessment

I did a Vulnerability Assessment for my database today. I found VA2108 and it suggests me to

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [dbo]
```

But it's the default setting of any SQL instance.

Should I go for it? And is there any risk?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't worry about it.

In fact, you cannot drop `dbo` from `db_owner`. There's a hard-wired blocker in the engine prohibiting you to do so. Try and you get the error:

```
Msg 15405, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot use the special principal 'dbo'.
```

Flagging `dbo` is a bug the assessment tool. The purpose of the assessment is to make sure one evaluates whether other members need those permissions.

Comment: Yeah people keep saying "don't worry about it" but not why, because it appears as though there is a user on my db that I don't want that has ownership rights of the db and I've no idea how to control or remove it, which is a SERIOUS security problem for me. I'd like to know why this isn't a problem, I've been told about this every week by Azure for nearly two years and still have no idea why, I'm not just approving the baseline and ignoring it, I want to know what it means. Microsoft told me they were going to fix it over a year ago.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like the vulnerability audit tool you use just always flags whenever a **User**, is mapped to the **db_owner** role, which in this case is the default **dbo**.

I believe there has to always be one **db_owner** of a database and as previously mentioned **dbo** is the default. So you won't be able to change this without first setting another **User** as the **db_owner**, which will get flagged by your audit anyway.

All things considered, this isn't the end of the world to leave as the default, as you *can* disable the **Login** associated with the **dbo** **User**.