# Should I provide db_owner principal role to the user of the Azure SQL of my Azure Web App?

Tags: security, azure-sql-database, vulnerability-assessment

I have an Azure Web App connected to an Azure SQL database. Let's call the app ACME. The application has it's own Role and User called ACME, and I gave that User `db_owner` principal roles. The authentication of the Web App is not Active Directory based, but it uses its own custom ASP.NET MVC based User and Role registry. Therefore the Web App creates Users and manages roles of those users, but those roles are technically not native SQL roles, but custom managed AspNetUserRoles. Seldom there are some schema changes and I perform the schema upgrades as ACME.

Recently the [Vulnerability Assessment rules got changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-vulnerability-assessment-rules-changelog) and V2130 got changed: it accepted `dbo` as `db_owner` by default before, but now it lists it if it's not part of the baseline. ~~Last year only ACME got added to my baseline~~. Now I need to decide:

1. Should I revoke `dbo`'s `db_owner` rights? That makes me feel weird because it's such a core part of SQL that by default SQL doesn't even let you revoke `dbo`'s `db_owner` rights. This is only possible if you have at least one other User who has such rights. In my case I have ACME.
2. Should I add `dbo` as a `db_owner` into my baseline besides ACME?
3. Should I add `dbo` as a `db_owner` into my baseline **and** curtail ACME's principals to not be so powerful as a `db_owner`. This is to adhere to the least privileges basic security rule. So should I downgrade ACME to for example to a `db_ddladmin`. I was thinking about DDL admin because of the occasional schema changes.

More generally: what could be the most secure and best practices (regarding User privileges and principles) for this common scenario?

Exhibit A: VA2130 query before 2020 December, watch the `principal_name != 'dbo'`:

```sql
WITH UsersAndRoles (principal_name, sid, type) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT prin.name, prin.sid, prin.type 
    FROM sys.database_principals prin 
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
                     FROM sys.database_permissions
                     WHERE type = 'CO' 
                        AND state IN ('G', 'W')
        ) perm 
            ON perm.grantee_principal_id = prin.principal_id 
        WHERE prin.type IN ('S', 'X', 'R', 'E', 'G')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        user_name(rls.member_principal_id), prin.sid, prin.type
    FROM 
        UsersAndRoles cte
        INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members rls
            ON user_name(rls.role_principal_id) = cte.principal_name
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals prin
            ON rls.member_principal_id = prin.principal_id
        WHERE cte.type = 'R'
),
Users (database_user, sid) AS
(
    SELECT principal_name, sid
    FROM UsersAndRoles
    WHERE type IN ('S', 'X', 'E', 'G')
        AND principal_name != 'dbo'
)
SELECT DISTINCT database_user AS [User], sid AS [SID]
    FROM Users
    WHERE sid != 0x01
```

Exhibit B: VA2130 query after the 2020 December rule changes:

```sql
WITH UsersAndRoles (principal_name, sid, type) AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT prin.name, prin.sid, prin.type 
    FROM sys.database_principals prin 
        INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions perm 
            ON perm.grantee_principal_id = prin.principal_id 
        WHERE prin.type in ('S', 'X', 'R')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        user_name(rls.member_principal_id), prin.sid, prin.type
    FROM 
        UsersAndRoles cte
        INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members rls
            ON user_name(rls.role_principal_id) = cte.principal_name
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals prin
            ON rls.member_principal_id = prin.principal_id
        WHERE cte.type = 'R'
),
Users (database_user, sid) AS
(
    SELECT principal_name, sid
    FROM UsersAndRoles
    WHERE type in ('S', 'X')
)
SELECT DISTINCT database_user, sid
    FROM Users
    WHERE sid != 0x01
```

An extra note: I'm aware of [Should I drop dbo from the database role db_owner?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284571/should-i-drop-dbo-from-the-database-role-db-owner) however I think it's kinda negligent to just add `dbo` as a baseline and move on without thinking about and discussing the ACME User which many developers have in case of ASP.NET MVC and other apps.

---

Note: I was confused looking through multiple Vulnerability Scan items, and realized that ACME user thankfully does not have any kind of special database role!

---

Related to VA2108: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you saw my answer and Tibor's to [Should I drop dbo from the database role db_owner?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284571/should-i-drop-dbo-from-the-database-role-db-owner) you shouldn't be too concerned about the *legacy* `dbo` User.

For your `ACME` User, I agree you should follow the **least privileges security principal** and therefore if it doesn't need as wide of access as a `db_owner` then remove it from that role and add only the roles or individual privileges that your `ACME` user does need.

So I would advise your third option as your path forward.

Comment: I got confused by looking at multiple VAxyz rules and fortunately ACME user is regular SQL_USER, doesn't have any special role like db_owner.